# Datatables locate row by key value. Retrieve content and remove row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable built server side with heading row and subsequent tr,td's

```
                                    <table id="referralList" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><div class="checkbox abc-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes"><label></label></div></th>
                                            <th>Referral Id</th>
                                            <th>Practice</th>
                                            <th>Patient</th>
                                            <th>Type</th>
                                            <th>NHI</th>
                                            <th>Injury Site</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Referral Date</th>
                                            <th>Contact</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="ackbutton">
                                            <tr id="69b9fb6c-ba8c-43e5-99bf-84c89aca27f3" role="row">
                                                <td><div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-success"><input name="69b9fb6c-ba8c-43e5-99bf-84c89aca27f3" type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes"><label></label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="xbtn xbtn-success" name="69b9fb6c-ba8c-43e5-99bf-84c89aca27f3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-69b9fb6c-ba8c-43e5-99bf-84c89aca27f3">HTI1034</a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Test Practice</td>
                                                <td>SAMPLE Test</td>
                                                <td>MRI</td>
                                                <td>ZXX0032</td>
                                                <td>C-Spine</td>
                                                <td>32</td>
                                                <td><span class="hide">20180925120000</span>25 Sep 2018</td>
                                                <td>02122222222</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="69b9fb6c-ba8c-43e5-99bf-84c89aca27f3">Acknowledge</button>
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr id="cc6c8709-d22f-de71-e6a1-ee8c4c9eaaf7" role="row">
                                                <td><div class="checkbox abc-checkbox abc-checkbox-success"><input name="cc6c8709-d22f-de71-e6a1-ee8c4c9eaaf7" type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes"><label></label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="xbtn xbtn-success" name="cc6c8709-d22f-de71-e6a1-ee8c4c9eaaf7" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-cc6c8709-d22f-de71-e6a1-ee8c4c9eaaf7">HTI8114265</a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>ABC Medical Centre</td>
                                                <td>WALTER White</td>
                                                <td>MRI</td>
                                                <td>JZZ3427</td>
                                                <td>L-SPINE</td>
                                                <td>60</td>
                                                <td><span class="hide">20170805083806</span>05 Aug 2017</td>
                                                <td>05-123-3456</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="cc6c8709-d22f-de71-e6a1-ee8c4c9eaaf7">Acknowledge</button>
                                                    </td>

                                            </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

I have managed to dynamically remove a row from the "Acknowledge" button on the table row with

```
table.api().row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
```

Which works perfectly well.

Two things I would like to be able to achieve

1. Be able to retrieve data from a cell after locating the correct row with the guid id on the  for example.
2. Perform the "remove row" (as above) by first locating the row with the  container guid and then removing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some persistence and the Chrome console I have the answers to my questions.

Possibly this may save somebody trying to achieve something similar.  I am not sure its the best way to do it but it works.

Question 1

```
 var retrievedValue = $(table.api().row(#id_of_the_row).data()[1])[0].innerHTML;
```

Question 2

```
table.api().row(#id_of_the_row).remove().draw(false);
```

Easy really...